# How strip the quotation from the meta descrption?

Tags: description

I checked the HTML validator.
But, the message is the following.

> Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing
>   somewhere earlier.

The meta description is automatic from the content. So, if the content includes the quotation, it is also included in meta descrption. I would like to strip the quotation.

Currently, I inserted the code in header.php as below.

```
$description = strip_shortcodes($description); 
$description = wp_strip_all_tags($description);
```

What should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it works for HTML5 Validator.

> $description =
> str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"," ",'"',"'"),'',$description);
>
> $description = strip_shortcodes($description);
>
> $description = wp_strip_all_tags($description);

First quotation is removed, but second one is not removed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Yoast SEO: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

It's the best plugin for SEO in WP and should be strips all "dangerous" chars

Comment: Thank you for the info.
But, at first, I'd like to try without plugin.
Anyone else?

Comment: In php you can use str_replace, for example: str_replace('"','',$metaDescription); or also use addslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried `$description = str_replace('"','',$description);`, But, nothing changed.

Comment: Moreover, I tried `$description = htmlentities($description);` code, the quotation was removed. But, it appeared &quot; etc codes instead of the quotation....

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111887/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string/27944589